# Spring Throwing 'UnsatisfiedDependencyException' on 'methodValidationPostProcessor'

Tags: spring-boot, grails

I am migrating my application from Grails 2.5.6 -> 3.3.5. So far I have only moved in my domain classes along with a few services that are required in the domain class. The application compiles and then it appears to attempt to start but fails. Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
07:23:34 computer:/workspace/grails3_proj$ grails run-app
| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...

| Running application...
Note: /workspace/grails3_proj/src/main/groovy/java/adaptive/UserInputException.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2018-06-13 07:24:22.046 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at grails3_proj.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:927)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:206)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
        ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindManyToOneValues(GrailsDomainBinder.java:2473)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindManyToOne(GrailsDomainBinder.java:2286)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.createClassProperties(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1912)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindSubClass(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1617)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindSubClass(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1502)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindSubClasses(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1435)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindRoot(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1400)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.contribute(GrailsDomainBinder.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:276)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        ... 51 common frames omitted


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

As you can see spring is throwing an unsatisfied dependency exception. My connection from application.yml is below and seems to follow proper formatting.

```
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: grails3_proj
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
    gorm:
        reactor:
            # Whether to translate GORM events into Reactor events
            # Disabled by default for performance reasons
            events: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false
    profiles: development

# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: true
        provider_class: org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
        region: 
            factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: "user"
    password: "pw"

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db_name?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&autoReconnect=true
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db_name?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&autoReconnect=true
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db_name?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&autoReconnect=true
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

I have the following dependencies in my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.8"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "grails3_proj"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { 
        url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" 
        artifactUrls "https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/"  // For aspose dirs
        artifactUrls "https://dl.bintray.com/grails/" 
        artifactUrls "https://dl.bintray.com/grails/plugins/"  // For most things not in Maven
        artifactUrls "https://dl.bintray.com/grails/grails-core/" 
        artifactUrls "https://dl.bintray.com/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/" 
        artifactUrls "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"
        artifactUrls "https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/"
        artifactUrls "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.8"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb:1.1.2"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
    // end of default imports

    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.5.Final"

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-imaging', version: '1.0-R1534292'

    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13' //prev 5.5.6
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itext-xtra', version: '5.5.13' //prev 5.5.6

    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.17' // prev 3.12
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17' // prev 3.12
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'openxml4j', version: '1.0-beta' // was previously: compile 'libRepo:openxml4j_android-src-beta:090725'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.17'

    runtime group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.46'

}


bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Am I missing a dependency? What would cause this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked this [Upgrading from Grails 2.x](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.x/guide/upgrading.html#upgrading2x)

These many repo not required,so please change it with bellow block of code:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
```

If you are using latest version of MySQL, The driver class and dependencies are changed:

```
dependencies {
  runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6"
}
```

and application.yml should contain:

```
production:
       dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                pooled: true
                url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true
                driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Have you check cache documentation, Please check [here](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#caching) and [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-ehcache/guide/usage.html)

I have following hibernate configuration:

```
 hibernate:
      cache:
        use_second_level_cache: true
        provider_class: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
        region:
           factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

If you are using lower version of MySql, please use MySQL dependency according to it. You can check all MySQL dependency version [here](http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/mysql/mysql-connector-java/)

> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

For this please try to increase heap space. Commonly while starting application, It takes huge memory.

Have you checked last error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindManyToOneValues(GrailsDomainBinder.java:2473)

i think you need to check your domain classes and its relation also.

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Apparently moving my datasource properties to within the environment properties within appllication.yml fixed it. No idea why this would be the issue but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
{
    ...  
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure') { excludes "hibernate-validator"}
}
```

Find a similar answer here: [Spring Boot: New Project - UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421606/spring-boot-new-project-unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean-w)

Answer (score 0):

Missed hibernate config in **application.yml**. For example:

```
hibernate:
  cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
```

Comment: My apologies - I should have just included the entire application.yml the first time around. I've edited the question and it now has the entire file.

Comment: So you use ehcache -  add "compile org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.5.Final" to your build.gradle

Comment: I've added the dependency to the build.gradle file but am still receiving the same error. I did run a clean prior to grails run-app. I also included my entire build.gradle file in the edited original question. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: What about adding 'region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'' to config?

Comment: Still getting the same error. Are you thinking it's along the lines of GORM failing to connect or issues with the new GORM/hibernate syntax? FYI: I'm moving from hibernate 3 to 5.

Comment: When I moved project from from grails 2 to 3 it was a lot of errors with wrong dependencies and configuration. Try "gradle dependecies" and check output. You'll probably find some problems.